# Should I use a hyphen in this sentence?

Tags: hyphens

I have an information technology terminology which is "rule". each rule consists of a premise, which is the part before the equal sign, and a conclusion, which is the part after the equal sign.
Example:

> *If temperature is low then the weather is cold.*

the premise is "temperature is low", while the conclusion is "weather is cold".

#### My question

I wrote this:

"*temperature is low*" is the first rule's premise.

should I use a hyphen ("-") between "first" and "rule"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Absolutely not.***

What we are looking at here, is a simple pair of adjective + noun.

Grammatically speaking the same pattern as:

> - green shoes
> - dusty attic
> - last winter
> - ...

Therefore: No, there is no hyphen. Your phrase remains as:

> *"Temperature is low"* is the first rule's premise.

Comment: I agree. If the O.P. found that wording awkward for some reason, this alternative could be used instead: _"temperature is low" is the premise of the first rule._ But there's nothing wrong with the original, and, as you say, it should not be hyphenated.